# replace lines in a text with matching text

Tags: bash, sed

Original file

```
123|abc|heloo good morning friends|1|123|abc|123|abc
123|abc|heloo good morning everyone|1|123|abc|123|abc
```

Replaced file

```
123|abc|heloo good morning freinds|1|123|abc|123|abc
123|abc|this is what i want to see|1|123|abc|123|abc
```

Here as you can see the separator is `|`. Now if any block contains the word "everyone" that particular block should be changed to "this is what i want to see".

Answer (score 4):

Just loop through the fields and check if they match or not:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
           if ($i ~ "everyone") $i="this is what i want to see"
      print}' file
```

See output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ "everyone") $i="this is what i want to see"; print}' file
123|abc|heloo good morning friends|1|123|abc|123|abc
123|abc|this is what i want to see|1|123|abc|123|abc
```

In a more idiomatic way, the `if` condition can be written as `($i ~ "everyone") && $i="this is what i want to see"` and then just use a true condition to print the lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) ($i ~ "everyone") && $i="this is what i want to see"} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/[^|]*everyone[^|]*/this is what I want to see/g' <<\DATA
123|abc|heloo good morning friends|1|123|abc|123|abc                       
123|abc|heloo good morning everyone|1|123|abc|123|abc
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
123|abc|heloo good morning friends|1|123|abc|123|abc
123|abc|this is what I want to see|1|123|abc|123|abc
```

This matches any occurence of *everyone* and the entire sequence to either left or right of it up to but not including the separator *|*. So the above works. But so does:

```
sed 's/[^|]*everyone[^|]*/replace/g' <<\DATA
everyone|everyevery|every|one|                                             
everyone|everyone|heloo good morning everyone|everyone|123|abc|123|abc
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
replace|everyevery|every|one|
replace|replace|replace|replace|123|abc|123|abc
```

Comment: this will not work. OP needs to apply only for strigns with `everyone`. And obviously not only for the second line.

Comment: Look more carefully on patterns to replace. ps. downvote is not from me.

Comment: @rush - dang man. How'd I miss that? I deserved the downvote - it all blended in. Anyway, that's fixed.